# Reutilização de código em react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Tenho um código que se repete em todas as páginas.

Como posso resolver esse problema reutilizando o script.

```
export default class App extends Component<{}> {
   onMenuItemSelected = item =>{
      if(item == "inicial")
      {
         Actions.inicial();
      }
      else if(item == "agendamento")
      {
         Actions.agendamento();
      }
   }

   render() {
      const menu = <Menu onItemSelected={this.onMenuItemSelected} />;
      return (
         ...
      );
   }
}
```

No caso eu gostaria de reutilizar o código do `onMenuItemSelected`.

Comment: Existem várias maneiras de se fazer isso, se você der mais detalhes sobre como é esta aplicação, será mais fácil de encontrar a melhor solução.

Comment: Eu tenho um menu "hamburguer" que é uma View separada, e em cada página estou repetindo esse código que é a chamada carregar outras "páginas" do app, eu tentei colocar no mesmo código do menu, mas eu precisaria criar um arquivo onde eu possa colocar os códigos globais.

Comment: Você pode fazer um componente pai como um `<Layout/>` por exemplo e manter tudo que é global nesse componente. Dentro dele vc mantém um placeholder `children` ou mais de um placeholder se for o caso, para vc ir alimentando esse `<Layout/>` com o conteúdo da página.

Answer (score 1):

Uma maneira é criar o seu próprio componente para o Menu:

```
class MeuMenu extends Component {
   onMenuItemSelected = item =>{
      if(item == "inicial")
      {
         Actions.inicial();
      }
      else if(item == "agendamento")
      {
         Actions.agendamento();
      }
   }

   render() {
      return <Menu onItemSelected={this.onMenuItemSelected} />;
   }
}
```

E utilizá-lo em qualquer lugar:

```
export default class App extends Component<{}> {
   render() {
      const menu = <MeuMenu />;
      return (
         ...
      );
   }
}
```